# knockout valueUpdate not working with Pagedown?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding, pagedown

I have the following in my view:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: content, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
```

Which when typing, behaves as I'd expect.  But I'm using a WMD / Pagedown editor to click a button that adds content to the field, much like StackOverflow's post contents box when you're creating / updating a post.

If I just click a button (to add  asterisks or brackets etc) and don't type anything, the value never gets updated in the `content` observable.

I do have a `save` button that I could use to trigger the "sync" before saving the data by specifiying the input elements to update, but I have no idea if that's possible.  What's the proper way to handle this situation?

Update: Jsfiddle to demo the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BcuLq/

**Update 2:** This behavior is also happening with a datetime datepicker that I'm using to populate an input with a string.  Any generic solution that I can apply to all programatically-filled inputs would be ideal, though I'm not sure if that's a reasonable way to go about this.

Comment: maybe you could put something in jsFiddle?  `valueUpdate` does accept an array of events `['afterkeydown', 'paste', 'input']`, so if you can determine what event or events are triggered when you click the button and update the field then it should work naturally. Also `change` is always included.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer finally got one together: http://jsfiddle.net/BcuLq/  Reproducable if you highlight the text and apply any styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a genuine use-case for using a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).  I implemented TinyMCE against a `<textarea>` successfully with this method.

The problem you are observing is the manipulations you make by clicking buttons on the tool bar are raising events on the `Markdown.Editor` which alters the value of the underlying `<textarea>` without the `change` event being fired, which of course Knockout relies upon in order to notify it's subscribables.

My solution implements a custom binding to ensure that events raised by the wysiwyg editor are reflected in the view-model.  Specifically, to ensure that the value is always up-to-date as well as maintaining a `dirty` flag in the view-model.  Since I am unfamiliar with the Markdown plug-in I have included a sample taken from my TinyMCE solution.  The principle will be exactly the same you will just need to apply the specifics of the Markdown editor.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wysiwyg = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).tinymce({
            /*** other options excluded for brevity ***/
            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.on('change', function() {
                    valueAccessor()(editor.getContent());
                    viewModel.isDirty = editor.isDirty();
                });
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).text(valueAccessor()());
    }
};
```

Finally your binding can now be implemented as follows;

```
<textarea data-bind="value: content, wysiwyg: content"></textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

Since reading up on PageDown, here is the custom binding taken from the fork of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92z35/1/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wysiwyg = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
            $(element).change();
        });
        editor.run();
    }
};
```

Comment: Apologies for my delay to clarifying this, I have since read-up on `PageDown` and forked your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92z35/1/) with an example. I hope this helps.